# running dd multiple times on same file with a counting variable for outputting multiple files

Tags: bash

Hard to cram what I'm trying to do into the title this is to process the command multiple times:

```
dd bs=12345 if=filename.static of=filename+variable(number_counting_upwards).suffix count=(number_starting_at_1234_to_12345)
```

eg:

```
dd bs=12345 if=filename.static of=filename_1234 count=1234
```

to

```
dd bs=12345 if=filename.static of=filename_12345 count=12345
```

Hope that makes sense :-/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean, but perhaps you need this:

```
$ echo {1234..12345}
1234 1235 1236 1237 1238 1239 1240 [snip] 12337 12338 12339 12340 12341 12342 12343 12344 12345
```

You could then do:

```
for i in {1234..12345}
do
    echo dd bs=12345 if=filename.static of=filename_$i count=$i
done
```

Remove the `echo` if the commands look OK.

Comment: Many thanks for the assistance I wasn't explaining things very well, really appreciate the help ;-)

Comment: Not portable I guess, what about `seq`?

Comment: @0andriy sure, `for i in $(seq 1234 12345) ...`, but no reason to use it here, I suppose - if you have `seq`, you likely have bash as well.

Comment: @muru, no, I don't have bash :-)

Answer (score 0):

I used a script with an `until` loop in the end:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
x=99000
until [ $x = "150000" ]; do
        dd bs=1 if=static.file of=static_${x}.file count=$x
    ((x++))
done
```

Comment: What about `seq`?